# How to use NuxtLink and send data through pages

Tags: vue.js, url, hyperlink, nuxt.js, nuxt-link

I am facing a problem with Nuxt Link:

-First i make a **v-for** to build some html

```
   <li v-for="loja in lojas">
        <p>{{loja.nomeEmpresa}}</p>
        <p> {{loja.url}} </p>
        <NuxtLink :to="nextPage">Configurar</NuxtLink>
        <b-button>Visualizar</b-button>
   </li>
```

**This object loja have {url,id}**

So, my problem is: How to use NuxLink and pass this id to my next page?

My idea is something like, that **does not work**:

```
       <NuxtLink :to="nextPage?usuarioId=${{loja.id}}">Configurar</NuxtLink>
```

Anyone know how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a template literal, like:

```
<NuxtLink :to="`nextPage?usuarioId=${loja.id}`">Configurar</NuxtLink>
```

Comment: Thanks!! I had given up about this. It works!! thanks so much!

And the way i manage to get this data at the next page is using

```  this.$route.query.(the data that i just sent)   ```